# fast xls conversion on linux

Tags: linux, type-conversion, xls

I need to extract text from an xls file for purpose of indexing. This is just an indexing requirement so formatting , macros sheets etc are of no concern,

using xlhtml  is very heavy and heavily brings down the indexing capability.

What is the best way for this conversion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used tika http://tika.apache.org/  as a daemon. 
Works much better now